# RxJS design pattern for multiple async calls

Tags: rxjs

I am new to RxJS and haven't been able to find clear answers on the following use case:

In a mobile app (Angular/Ionic), I need to (1) make simultaneous HTTP calls and only return data when all have completed (like $q.all). I want to (2) throw an error if the calls work correctly but there is a nested value in one of the responses that meets a certain criteria (ie user is not authenticated properly). Because it's a mobile app, I want to (3) build in a few retry attempts if the calls don't work correctly (for any reason). If after a certain number of retry attempts the calls still fail, I want to (4) throw an error.

Based on my research seems like forkJoin works the same as q.all. I have a provider that returns the following (observableArray holds the http calls).

```js
return Observable.forkJoin(observableArray)
```

And then I can pipe in some operators, which is where I'm starting to struggle. For checking the nested value (2), I am using an underscore method to iterate over each response in my response array. This doesn't seem clean at all.

For retrying the calls (3), I am using retryWhen and delayWhen. But I am unsure how to limit this to 3 or 4 attempts.

And if the limit is hit, how would I throw an error back to the subscribers (4)?

```js
.pipe(
    map(
        res => {
            _.each(res, (obs) => {
                if (!obs['success']) throw new Error('success was false')
            })
        }
    ),
    retryWhen(attempts =>
        attempts.pipe(
            tap(err => console.log('error:', err),
                delayWhen(() => timer(1000))
            )
        )
    ))
```

Comment: You should not rely on {sucess:true} json value for error routing, the backend should send over header code 400 or 500 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of tricks here to make your code clean.

**1. Use [`Observable.iif()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif):**

> iif accepts a condition function and two Observables. When an Observable returned by the operator is subscribed, condition function will be called. Based on what boolean it returns at that moment, consumer will subscribe either to the first Observable (if condition was true) or to the second (if condition was false).

**2. Use JavaScript array native's [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)**:

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

**3. Use [`take()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take) to terminate your `retryWhen`**

> Emits only the first count values emitted by the source Observable.

So your code boils down to:

```js
.pipe(
    switchMap((res) => iif(
        () => res.every(({success}) => success),
        res,//if every element in res is successful, return it
        throwError('success was false') //else if any of it is false, throw error.
        )
    ),
    retryWhen(err => err.delay(1000).take(4))
)
```

**Edit:**

If you want to catch the error at your subscribe, you will need to rethrow the error. `.take()` will actually just terminate the sequence, aka completing it:

```js
.pipe(
    switchMap((res) => iif(
        () => res.every(({success}) => success),
        res,//if every element in res is successful, return it
        throwError('success was false') //else if any of it is false, throw error.
        )
    ),
    retryWhen(err => {
        return errors.scan((errorCount, err) =>
            (errorCount >= 4 ? //is retried more than 4 times?
                    throwError(err) : //if yes, throw the error
                    errorCount++ //else just increment the count
            ), 0);
    })
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks great! I was using RxJS 5.5 so I upgraded to RxJS 6 to take advantage of iif. Seem to be getting a TypeScript error having to do with the conditional. Is saying "argument of type '(res: any) => () => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => boolean'". I also tried to dumb it down (for myself) by using just () => true as my conditional. Any thoughts?

Comment: @shaunmwa my bad. Observable.iif doesnt take in any argument for its first callback. You just need to use a `switchMap()` and all is good. See edited

Comment: Great! This seems to be working...EXCEPT my throwError message isn't appearing anywhere. Again for sake of testing, I just returned false in the conditional. The forkJoin is retried 3 additional times and then cancelled...but the throwError message doesn't make it back to my subscriber. `.subscribe((res) => {console.log(res)}, (err) => {console.log(err)}` Thanks for all of your help. This is tricky!

Comment: @shaunmwa you will need to re-throw the error. See the new code.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility to consider is to pipe the various operators you need, e.g. `retry` and `map`, into each Observable contained in the `observableArray` you pass to `forkJoin`.

The code could look like something similar to this

```js
const observableArray = new Array<Observable<any>>();
const maxRetries = 4;

function pipeHttpObservable(httpObs: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
   return httpObs
      .pipe(
         map(data => data.success ? data : throwError('success was false')),
         retryWhen(err => err.delay(1000).take(maxRetries))
      )
}

observableArray.push(pipeHttpObservable(httpObs1));
observableArray.push(pipeHttpObservable(httpObs2));
.....
observableArray.push(pipeHttpObservable(httpObsN));

forkJoin(observableArray).subscribe(result => do stuff with the results)
```